# What does $.support.placeholder mean in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't understand this condition: `$.support.placeholder`

Can anyone explain to me what this is for?

```
if ($.support.placeholder) { 
  alert("Testing"); 
} else { 
  return; 
}
```

Comment: `placeholder` is not a property in the latest version of jQuery's [`$.support`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.support/) implementation. Unless you've added it yourself it's not going to work. Also note that the `support` object is deprecated, so you really should not rely on it for feature detection. Something like Modernizr would be more reliable.

Comment: Jquery doesn't have `placeholder` prop in `$.support`, this must be user defined variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's checking to see if the `placeholder` property on the `$.support` object is *truthy*¹ and, if so, it does the `alert`; if not, it does a `return`, exiting the function this code is in.

jQuery's [`support`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) object (**long** deprecated, it shouldn't be used anymore) tells you what the current browser supports. From the link:

> A collection of properties that represent the presence of different browser features or bugs. Intended for jQuery's internal use; **specific properties may be removed when they are no longer needed internally to improve page startup performance**. For your own project's feature-detection needs, we strongly recommend the use of an external library such as [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) instead of dependency on properties in `jQuery.support`.

*(my emphasis)*

In this case, the check is seeing if the browser supports the `placeholder` attribute on `input` elements. But see above, the check is unreliable. If jQuery no longer needs to know this information internally, the property may be removed, and that code would be tricked into thinking the browser didn't support `placeholder` (which nearly all do) because getting the value of a property that doesn't exist results in `undefined`, which is falsy.

In fact, the current version of jQuery as of this writing (v3.3.1) doesn't have `placeholder`:

```js
console.log("typeof $.support.placeholder:", typeof $.support.placeholder); // "typeof $.support.placeholder: undefined"
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
var supportsPlaceholder = "placeholder" in input;
console.log("supportsPlaceholder: ", supportsPlaceholder); // "supportsPlaceholder: true" (in nearly all browsers)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The code in the question would incorrectly report that your browser doesn't have `placeholder` support even when it does.

---

¹ a *truthy* value is a value that coerces to `true` when used as a boolean, such as in an `if`. A *falsy* value is one that coerces to `false`. The falsy values are `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`, and of course, `false`; all other values are truthy.